# How to generate a population of random numbers within a certain exponentially increasing range

Tags: r, statistics

I have 16068 datapoints with values that range between 150 and 54850 (`mean = 3034.22`). What would the R code be to generate a set of random numbers that grow in frequency exponentially between 54850 and 150?

I've tried using the `rexp()` function in R, but can't figure out how to set the range to between 150 and 54850. In my actual data population, the lambda value is 25.

```
set.seed(123)
myrange <- c(54850, 150)
rexp(16068, 1/25, myrange)
```

The call produces an error.

```
Error in rexp(16068, 1/25, myrange) : unused argument (myrange)
```

The hypothesized population should increase exponentially the closer the data values are to 150. I have 25 data points with a value of 150 and only one with a value of 54850. The simulated population should fall in this range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really more of a question for [math.stackexchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/), but out of curiosity I provide this solution. Maybe it is sufficient for your needs.

First, `?rexp` tells us that it has only two arguments, so we generate a random exponential distribution with the desired length.

```
set.seed(42)         # for sake of reproducibility
n <- 16068
mr <- c(54850, 150)  # your 'myrange' with less typing

y0 <- rexp(n, 1/25)  # simulate exp. dist.
y <- y0[order(-y0)]  # sort
```

Now we need a mathematical approach to rescale the distribution.

```
# f(x) = (b-a)(x - min(x))/(max(x)-min(x)) + a
y.scaled <- (mr[1] - mr[2]) * (y - min(y)) / (max(y) - min(y)) + mr[2]
```

*Proof:*

```
> range(y.scaled)
[1]   150.312 54850.312
```

That's not too bad.

*Plot:*

```
plot(y.scaled, type="l")
```

[image]

*Note:* There might be some mathematical issues, see therefore e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33577835/6574038).

Comment: Thanks so much, @jay.sf. There is a small bit of trouble with the scaled code:
    
    `y.scaled <- (mr[1] - mr[2]) * (y - min(y)) / (max(y) - min(y)) + mr[2]`

Once I put it in that way, it worked perfectly.

Comment: Very welcome. Just a typo thanks, I've edited it. Please [mark the question as answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/371738), this will stop people spending time on answering a question that has already been answered, thanks.